# Using seed or migration exs to create stored procedure

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have some existing Java web based applications, and I want it to make the Phoenix version of those.

Some of my existing have many stored procedures. How can I use migration or seed exs to create those stored procedures? Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: There's a guide about seeding data maybe this could help: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/seeding-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the migration. You should implement the creation in the `up` function and the removal in the `down` function. Use the  `execute` command in a migration to run arbitrary sql.

```
def up do
  execute "INSERT INTO add_col_migration (value, to_be_added) VALUES (1, 2)"
end

def down do
  execute "..."
end
```

See the docs https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1